# Push in array if key exists

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Viettel
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559881644000,500
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => FPT
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559994465000,172
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => MobiFone
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559997314000,11164
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Vietnamobile
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559993699000,1246
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Viettel
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1560000096000,47886
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => VinaPhone
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559997553000,11132
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => VNPT
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559993066000,84
                )

        )

)
```

I'm currently using a foreach loop to extract the values from the array:

```
      $result = [];
        $nameData = [];
        foreach($data as $key => $itemData)
        {

        }
```

I want array look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Viettel
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559881644000,500
                    [1] => 1560000096000,47886
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => FPT
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559994465000,172
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => MobiFone
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559997314000,11164
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Vietnamobile
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559993699000,1246
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => VinaPhone
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559997553000,11132
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => VNPT
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1559993066000,84
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for groupby the array by `name`.

You can use `foreach` with `array_key_exists` and `array_push`

```
 $groupBy = [];
 foreach($a as $v){
   array_key_exists($v['name'], $groupBy) ? 
    array_push($groupBy[$v['name']]['data'], $v['data'][0])
   :
    ($groupBy[$v['name']] = $v)
   ;
 }
```

If you want to rearrange the keys of array, you can use `array_values`

```
 print_r(array_values($groupBy));
```

Working DEMO :- https://3v4l.org/ASWDV

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over the input array, adding values to the output if they don't exist and merging that data values if they do:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $itemData) {
    if (($k = array_search($itemData['name'], array_column($result, 'name'))) !== false) {
        $result[$k]['data'] = array_merge($result[$k]['data'], $itemData['data']);
    }
    else $result[] = $itemData;
}
print_r($result);
```

Output is as you desire (too long to reproduce here)

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jNr0X)

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a single value to the array you can just access to it with something like this:

```
$result[0]['data'][1] = 1560000096000,47886
```